# How important back referencing is on CloudKit?

Tags: ios, cloudkit

In WWDC 2014 lecturer ephasize `back referencing` is a strong advantage on CloudKit side. Do you think it realy counts, there are many MBaas provider who are more SQL, foreign key based.

Are foreign keys and `back referencing` two opposite approach?

How important role back referencing plays in scalability?

By the way which [platform independent MBaas technology similar to CloudKit do you recommend](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18901/platform-independent-alternatives-to-cloudkit)?

[image]

Comment: back referencing feels very similar to foreign keys. At the moment I'm using the back references as if they were foreign keys. It looks like the main difference is that it always is referencing the recordId and your can't reference any other fields. I'm not sure why this would be a strong advantage

Comment: I am guessing, but foreign key in SQL is forward reference (??), so when you add a record as a child in the foreign key relationship, that will put a lock at the parent, and if hundreds of clients do the same, writing get slow and cause a lot of conflicts